# Which conditions should I impose to make the sequence of partial sums be convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the following equation $x_{n+2} + (a − b)x_{n+1} + (a + b)x_n = 0$, which conditions should I impose to a and b to make the $S_n$ sequence of partial sums of a solution convergent ?($S_n=x_0+x_1+...+x_n$)

Comment: For any initial $x_0,x_1$?

Comment: Yes, I'm not given anything more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is linear: if $\{x_i\}, \{y_i\}$ are two sequences that obey it, and $A, B$ are constants, then $\{Ax_i + By_i\}$ also obeys it. Thus the set of solutions is a vector space. And because each solution is completely determined by the values of $x_0, x_1$, the vector space is 2-dimensional. Thus if you can find two independent solutions, all other solutions are linear combinations of those two.

For $x_n = r^n$ to be a solution, it must be that $r^2 + (a-b)r + (a+b) = 0$ or $$r = \frac {b-a \pm \sqrt{(a-b)^2 - 4(a+b)}}2$$
These two values of $r$ provide two independent solutions. Calling the values $r_1, r_2$, every solution is of the form $x_i = Ar_1^i + Br_2^i$, so the $n$-th partial sum is
$$S_n = A\sum_{i=0}^n r_1^i + B\sum_{i=0}^n r_2^i$$
from which it should be easy to see what is needed to ensure all such sums converge.

**Warning:** There is a hole in the argument above. Spot it, and we can discuss how it can be closed.

Comment: Ok, I got almost to this before, but don't know how to proceed to determine a and b, i think the way is making $\abs{r}<1$ but get stucked in those inequations. And another problem is what I think you are referring to with the 'hole', what happens when the square root content is negative?, how to deal with complex roots?

Comment: Yes, you need to make $|r| < 1$, so the trick is now to determine what $a, b$ make this true. Complex roots are not the hole (though this is close to the weakness). They actually take care of themselves. Since $a,b$ are real, any complex roots must come in conjugate pairs, and when they do $r_1^i$ and $r_2^i$ are also conjugate pairs. Just choose $A, B$ as conjugate pairs as well, and the resultant sequence $\{x_i\}$ is real-valued.

Comment: To see the hole, consider what happens when $a = 5/8$ and $b = -3/8$.

Comment: Yeah, I've reached similar with a=-1/2 b=3/2, basically when the equation has only one root. But this solutions that are in the way xn=(c1+c2n)r^n can still go to zero aren't they?

Comment: Another thing I dont know is if im coping with absolute value correctly, I got the condition if a>-1/2 but cant get b and i can find counterexamples that a isnt even correct, I think Im missing something...

Comment: Yes, if $|r| < 1$, then $\sum_n nr^n$ still converges. For the rest, solve the 4 inequalities $$-2 \le b-a - \sqrt{(a-b)^2-4(a+b)}\\2 \ge b-a - \sqrt{(a-b)^2-4(a+b)}\\-2 \le b-a + \sqrt{(a-b)^2-4(a+b)}\\2 \ge b-a + \sqrt{(a-b)^2-4(a+b)}$$ separately, then figure out how all 4 can be true at the same time. It might help to let $u = a-b$ and $v = 2b$.

Comment: Ok, i`ve found a lot of different situations. All cases of convergence come when a<-1/2 and b>-1/2. But, when a=b or a=-b, this conditions doesn´t hold always. Is this because they are not independent?

Comment: Note that $|a+b| < 1$ always for convergence ($a + b$ is the product of the two roots, and if they are both $<1$, then so is their product.). If $a < -\frac 12$ and $b > -\frac 12$ and $|a + b| < 1$, then neither $a = b$ nor $a = -b$ are possible.

Comment: Nice, noticing this now all works, thank you!!